# cannot find owncloud docker files for backup

Tags: linux, backup, docker, owncloud

I installed ownCloud via docker (only for LAN access) on an elementaryOS computer using the following tutorial: [Docker Series Pt.1: How to Set up an ownCloud in 3 Minutes](https://owncloud.org/news/how-to-set-up-an-owncloud-in-3-minutes/)

In part 3 of the same guide ([Docker Series Pt.3: Automatically Backup and Restore a Dockerized ownCloud](https://owncloud.org/news/docker-series-pt-3-automatically-easily-backup-restore-dockerized-owncloud/)) there are instructions to backup. Specifically:

```
sudo rsync -r /var/lib/docker/volumes/owncloud_files ../owncloud_backup/
sudo rsync -r /var/lib/docker/volumes/owncloud_mysql ../owncloud_backup/
```

However, even after stopping Docker and switching to superuser via `sudo -i`, the `/var/lib/docker/volumes` is completely empty.

What am I doing wrong here?

edit:
docker was installed by snap, therefore the volumes were inside some snap-owned directory

Comment: Please show your Dockerfile or docker-compose file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're having trouble finding where on your host system docker is saving your volumes use the following steps:

1. `docker volume ls` to find the volume name
2. `docker volume inspect VOLUME NAME` to show the details for the volume specified by `VOLUME NAME`

In the details it will show a mountpoint in your local file system.

Comment: Not sure if this will help. It's not even clear the OP is using volumes at all (particularly if `/var/lib/docker/volumes` is empty).

Comment: If he is following the guide posted he is using:
```
volumes:
  files:
    driver: local
  mysql:
    driver: local
  backup:
    driver: local
  redis:
    driver: local
[...]
```

Comment: thanks for your answers. i am using volumes, but the snap-install uses completely different directories.